# Angular UI-grid header style issues

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I am having issues with the grid header style. At times when it loads I can see the header, when I ungroup/group some thing then the header goes for a toss and the height is reducing and none of the column header text is shown.

Another issue is randomly I am seeing the filter text boxes. Not always.

They seem to be working fine at times.

I have downloaded the ui-grid.css and referencing from local.

Is there a known problem associated with it.?

UPDATE:
Attaching is the screen shot for the UI issues I am getting, I had added the plunker which does not have any issues with the styles.

[image: Screen shot attached]

Comment: Can you provide some of your code or make a Plunkr showing the issue?

Comment: Hi, The pluncker can be accessed at http://plnkr.co/edit/CnKAOuOn6tb7jI3BN0R0?p=preview.

Comment: Hi, For some reason the UI issues I was trying to generate is not happening. There are few other issues which I currently have can be seen in the example.  Please refer to tthe group "NE", the behavior is not right. I have 3 records for it so the group should show 3 records. But it shows two records but in two different places. I am not sure how do I resolve this issue